# Redis in Spring Boot, keeping the redis template

Tags: java, spring, redis

I have a problem with a project. I am creating a very primitive chat program, with spring and redis.

I have the redis connection as a Spring Bean:

```
private HashOperations hashOps;

@Autowired
public UserRepositoryImpl(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
}

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    hashOps = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
}
```

Until here everything seems to work, and the hashops is declared as template. But now I call

```
 public boolean createUser(User user){
        if(user.getName().isEmpty() || user.getPassword().isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        user.setStatus("");
        if(hashOps.putIfAbsent(KEY, user.getName(), user)){
            List<String> following = null;
            hashOps.put("isFollowing", user.getName(),following);
            FollowListImpl fLI = new FollowListImpl(this.redisTemplate);
            fLI.follow("global", user);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

to create the first data (a user), in redis. THis method is in the same class  as the declaration of `hashOps` but `hasOps` is now NULL. But when I use a project from someone else, who has a similar, solution `hashOps` keeps the template even through method calls.

Redis is Connected in the main class (starter class):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CommunicatorApplication {

@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
    jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName("localhost");
    jedisConnectionFactory.setPassword("");
    return jedisConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(getConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CommunicatorApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Now the question is, how does spring actually keep `hashOps` when it is working properly, and what did I do wrong, that it doesn't keep it in my code.

I call `createUser` here:

```
  @Controller
public class LoginController {
     @RequestMapping(value = "/login", params = "btnRegister")
    public String loginRegister(@ModelAttribute Login login, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("login", login != null ? login : new Login());
        UserRepositoryImpl user = new UserRepositoryImpl(null);
        user.createUser(login.getName(),login.getPassword());
        System.out.println(user.findUser(login.getName()));
        return "login";
    }
```

Comment: You need to show more of your code. It sounds like you are calling the constructor of the class that contains `hashOps` explicitly somewhere, instead of obtaining the bean from the Spring application context.

Comment: try this `jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet()`

Comment: @Deadpool
Didn't change anything, sadly.

Comment: @MarkB
I added where I call this method, but I am not doing anything else with it.

It isn't unlikely that I am missing something though, if you think there should be something more, let me know it, you would be likely right with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is instantiating a new instance of `UserRepositoryImpl`:

```
UserRepositoryImpl user = new UserRepositoryImpl(null);
```

This instance you are creating is not attached to Spring in any way. You are even explicitly passing `null` as the `redisTemplate` argument here, so of course this is not going to work.

You need to use the instance of `UserRepositoryImpl` that is created and managed by Spring. In order to do this you need to instruct Spring to wire the instance into the `LoginController`. One method of accomplishing this is to use the `@Autowired` annotation like so:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepositoryImpl userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", params = "btnRegister")
    public String loginRegister(@ModelAttribute Login login, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("login", login != null ? login : new Login());
        userRepository.createUser(login.getName(),login.getPassword());
        System.out.println(userRepository.findUser(login.getName()));
        return "login";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I completely forgot that I declared it as null, for testing purposes, since I didn't knew how to declare it properly.